# How can I do a synchronous request with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, synchronous

Why don't return that function the responseText?

```
function LoadBookmarksAsXml()
{
  return $.ajax(
  {
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url:  'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000'
  }).responseText;
}
```

(It works if I define a success-callback-function and set async to true!)
Thanks in advance!!

**Edit**: Don't worry about the cross-domain call; user603003 says (in a comment on a now-deleted answer) that this is in a Chrome extension where cross-domain requests are allowed.

***The solution if someone wants to do the same:***

```
return $.ajax(
{
  type: 'GET',
  async: false,
  url:  'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000',
});
```

(You will get a XMLHTTPRequest object.)

Comment: You mean *synchronous* request, right?

Comment: Can you post, what works? Might be something to do with a redirect?

Comment: @user: *"(You will get a XMLHTTPRequest object.)"* As of jQuery 1.5, you'll get a jqXHR object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqxhr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not immediately seeing why it's not returning it, but I'd still use a `success` callback:

```
function LoadBookmarksAsXml()
{
  var result;
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url:  'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000',
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Even though `$.ajax` returns an `XMLHttpRequest` object (in 1.4 or earlier) or a `jqXHR` object (in 1.5+), I'd still prefer using a `success` function and an `error` function for clarity. Also, different versions of jQuery give you different values for `responseText` on error (at least on Chrome; 1.4.4 returns an empty string, 1.5.0 returns `undefined`).

---

If there's **any way you can avoid it**, avoid it. Synchronous requests completely lock up the UI of most browsers (not just your page's UI, every page in every tab that browser is managing). Since ajax requests can take a second or two (or five, or ten), this makes for a very unpleasant user experience. Nearly all the time, you can avoid it by refactoring your function so it accepts a callback to use to supply the result:

```
function LoadBookmarksAsXml(callback)
{
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: 'GET',
    url:  'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/?output=xml&num=10000',
    success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        callback(null);
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: I'll be surprised if the request works at all, though, because on the face of it (unless you work for Google), that request will fail because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Various ways to get around the SOP:

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)
- [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (but it requires browser support and that www.google.com allow the request from your origin)
- [Using YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax)

Comment: @jAndy: Yeah, I noticed that when I went back to add the async example. I was copy-and-pasting the original code and removing the `async: false` and went "hey, wait, that's a google url!"

Comment: @inti: Oh, and what do you know, they've said (on a deleted answer) that it's for a Chrome extension where x-domain requests are allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the solution at the top of the page. Maybe I will edit that function to do a callback like you have done. (Note that Google uses for every a tab a single process but I don't know how it is with extensions)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder was my bad, sorry, deleted my comment and tried to take back the down vote, but didn't let me for 5 mins.

Comment: @user: If you want to answer your own question (which is perfectly fine to do), your best bet is to actually post an answer. Then after a couple of days, if yours is the best answer in your view, you can even accept your own answer. More: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` never returns the response text, it always returns the XMLHTTPRequest object created to make the Ajax call.

You'll still need to define a success callback I think, e.g. one setting a local variable which you can then return.

Standard disclaimer: Synchronous requests are a usually discouraged practice because they can freeze the current page.

Comment: Sorry but I don't need a success function I only need to return $.ajax(); it is a XMLHTTPRequest object like you have explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for the response of a function is not asyncronous, the ajax call will have a response when it is done, you have to take care of the response then, by defining callbacks for the successful event.

You have ti break up your code to at least two parts. First part is before the ajax call, second part is after the success, and put everything you want to do with the requested data in the success callback. Asyncronous requests work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that is a really bad idea. Javascript will block for the duration of the HTTP request, which is to say nothing else in the UI thread will run until the ajax call returns. Use a callback.

Answer (score 0):

By design, asynchronous requests can't deliver a responseText out of the blue ;-)
You HAVE to set a callback function and decide how you will handle the responseText.