# Loading JavaScript Inline

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load some JavaScript files inside another JavaScript file in the following case:

js/script1.js

```
var script_1_method = function () {
   console.log("Hello Script 1");
}
```

js/init-script.js

```
console.log("Initiating Scripts...");
loadScriptMethod('js/script1.js');
script_1_method();
console.log("Hello Script 2");
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init-script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The Console output should be

```
Initiating Scripts...
Hello Script 1
Hello Script 2
```

I have looked into many JavaScript loaders like curl.js, RequireJS, JSL almost all of them do an Asynchronous way of loading files requiring callbacks for my scenario.

Is there a library to load the scripts in a synchronous way as in the above case without requiring callbacks.

Please let me know if there are any JavaScript loader libraries which cater to the above case.

Comment: No need to sign your posts; you're writing questions, not letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to load same-origin scripts using a synchronous XHR:

```
var scr = getViaSynchronousXHR('js/script1.js'),
    el  = document.createElement("script");

el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scr));
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(el);
script_1_method();
```

A script element without a source is parsed and executed synchronously, because there is no wait for the file to be downloaded/fetched from cache.

Comment: Strangely only doing the getViaSynchronousXHR('js/script1.js') works without appending the script tag. I used this implementation of getViaSynchronousXHR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897193/how-can-i-do-an-synchronous-request-with-jquery

Comment: @Geek: if you're using jQuery, it automatically detects the script and uses much the same method to add it to the document.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/, which internally creates script elements and adds them to the document.

Answer (score 1):

if all your scripts are on the same domain, you can run a synchronous ajax call to get the script, use eval to run it, and then continue

Comment: Are you sure eval is the best thing to use here? eval seems evil to me (it's dangerous).

Comment: @Lajos: there's no difference in safety when executing a script with `eval` or just adding it to the document.  Unfortunately, getting `eval` to execute in the global scope is a cross browser conundrum.  Best to just create the script element and add it to the document.

Comment: Other then being synchronous and only single-domain capable, the only big problem of using eval for script loading is that it often gives very bad error messages if you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is quite difficult. I had a lot of problems with synchronous AJAX requests to correctly load my javascript files dynamically.

Actually I implemented something that worked synchronously on my project which is the same as you want.

It is only possible if you have a server-side scripting engine (e.g. PHP) to generate your HTML page.

The idea is to parse the init-scripts.js on server side prior to include them into the html code.

Instead of writing `echo <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init-script.js"></script>` in my PHP script I write : `JavascriptLoader::addJavascript('js/init-script.js');`

JavascriptLoader is a PHP class which manages scripts to be loaded.

This addJavascript function parses the init-script.js and, each time it encounters a line which starts with "*loadScriptMethod(*",

- it parses and uses the string between brackets (e.g `loadScriptMethod('thisString')`) as the scriptToLoad
- and then calls recursively `JavascriptLoader::addJavascript($scriptToLoad);`

`JavascriptLoader::addJavascript` then do an `echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$scriptToLoad.'"></script>'` to write

I cannot publish the JavascriptLoader code from my project, but here is a simplified example of PHP code:

```
class JavascriptLoader{
...
public static function  addJavascript($filepath){

    self::init(); //Init to write the javascript loadScriptMethod definition into HTML output

    if (!self::isScriptAlreadyLoaded($filepath)){
        self::parseFile($filepath);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$urlScript.'"></script>',"\n";
        self::ajouterScriptDejaCharge($chemin);
    }
}
private static function parseFile($filepath){
    if (file_exists($filepath)){
        $lines = file($filepath, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

        foreach($lines as $line){
            $matches = array();
            $test = preg_match ('/^loadScriptMethod\(\s*[\'\"](.+)[\'\"]\s*\)/'  , $line , $matches);
            if ($test > 0){
                $scriptToLoad = $matches[1];

                //On inclut le fichier
                self::addJavascript($scriptToLoad);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('javascript source file '.$filepath.' does not exist.');
    }
```

This also stores the $scriptToLoad into an array to avoid loading twice the same script (functions isScriptAlreadyLoaded and addScriptToAlreadyLoadedList).